# mmenu - how to know the state of the menu (if its open or closed)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mmenu

I am fairly new to jquery and javascript and I am trying to understand the mmenu API. I tried to make sense of the libraries but I honestly have no idea about the written js code.

Using the tutorial on the website http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/tutorials/basic/ , I made a basic menu. The problem is that, I can't make a button that will toggle the menu on click. I need to know the state of the menu to say

```
if(isMenuOpen){API.close();}else{API.open();}
```

Where can I learn the "menu state variable" of this given API?

It would be also okay if you can tell me how to find my way around in such API's. Like, where do people know this? I looked through the documentation and it is still vague to me, probably because I am a beginner. But I will study whatever if I know what to study in the first place.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you make sure the variable api is referencing the data attribute mmenu?

Comment: Yes, it was already there in the website. I copied it directly and I am able to open or close the menu by just writing one of them. Problem is, where do I get a variable like 'isMenuOpen' to be able to toggle with just one button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find anything that returns that state of the menu. One thing you could do with jQuery is check if the menu is visible or has the class mm-opened

```
function toggleMenu() {
    if($('#menu').hasClass('.mm-opened')) {
        API.close();
    } else {
        API.open();
    }
}
// alternative
function toggleMenu() {
    if($('#menu').is(':visible')) {
        API.close();
    } else {
        API.open();
    }
}
```

Comment: If condition should be like this.

`if ($('#Menu').hasClass('mm-menu_opened'))`